# What modern tactical knives do you think will become future classics?

Tags: weapons, military, future

I’m developing a costume for some military characters in a story set in 2156. What knives of today do you think could still be popular and in use by armed forces in 136 years? What are the Fairbairn-Sykes, Ka-Bars, or Ontario Air Force Survival Knives of today?

Comment: If you're talking about that level of future tech, are they still using conventional tech that regular knives will still make sense? We really need more information about the world to have a clear sense about what makes the most sense. Are these knives meant more as a tool or more as a weapon?

Comment: This is a good question although it needs way more info before I can answer. Specifically the need for a utility blade, the prevelance and type of armor they use, and the kinds of tactics employed. It would also depend on who your military is fighting, like if they are performing largely peacekeeping missions or fighting an asymmetrical war or on an equal footing. Maybe they're fighting aliens.